# How to show initial marker in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As per my question, I want to add an initial marker for the map, but it only shows me the marker when I enter address on load. If I want to show a marker like for longitude 41.008238 and latitude 28.978359, how can I make this possible? And sorry for my bad English.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.008238, 28.978359),
    zoom: 13
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {types: ['geocode']});
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
       var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
       var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng()); 
       map.setOptions({
           center: newPos,
           zoom: 15
       });
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: newPos,
           map: map,
           title:"market title"
       });
   });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>


  <div id="map-canvas">Loading map...</div>
<style>
    #map {
    /*  float:right;*/
  width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
#map-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: add var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.008238, 28.978359),
    map: map,
    title: 'market title'
  });
outside autocomplete listener block.

Comment: @Banik Ok let me try this

Comment: @Banik No success :(

Comment: one problem I found that there is no mapOptions and immediate line of initilaze function consists error it should be  mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.008238, 28.978359),
    zoom: 13};

Comment: @Banik hey i just figured it out that you have suggested in first comment.  just added that below the var map variable and now its working you can post this as answer i will accept it

Comment: just posted as answer...

Comment: @Banik ya done.. :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.008238, 28.978359),
    map: map, 
    title: 'market title' 
});
```

below

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
        //lat0 = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
        //lng0 = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
        //lat1 = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
        //lng1 = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
        get_markers();
    });
function get_markers(){
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latit, longit,
        map: map
    });
}
```